# Display the inside of the array in React js

Tags: reactjs

When i console log the stepData it shows what i need as seen below, but when i try to console log the historicalSapboxCheck where here stores my stepData, it shows only the two last of my array that is why in my typography the logs of historicalSapboxCheck is shown

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSapboxDataUser = async () => {
      const data = await getHistoricalChecks();
  
      const checklistData = data.data.data;
  
      for (let i = 0; i < checklistData.length; i++) {
        const stepData = checklistData[i].checklist_data;
        console.log("stepData:", stepData);
        setHistoricalSapboxCheck(stepData)
      }
  
    };
  
    fetchSapboxDataUser();
  }, []);

  console.log("stepData:", historicalSapboxCheck);

return (
    <>
      <Typography
        sx={{
          margin: '2rem 6rem',
          fontSize: '1.5rem',
          color: 'primary.main',
          float: 'left',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        }}
      >
        Historical Check
      </Typography>
      <Box sx={boxStyle}>
    {sapboxData.map((sapboxDataItem, index) => {
      const matchingSapboxCheck = historicalSapboxCheck[sapboxDataItem.sapboxName];
      const sapboxCheckExists = matchingSapboxCheck && matchingSapboxCheck.length > 0;

      return (
        <Accordion
          style={{ outline: 'none' }}
          key={index}
          elevation={0}
          expanded={expandedAccordion === index}
          onChange={() => handleAccordionChange(index)}
        >
          <DialogTitle sx={nameBoxStyle} key={index}>
            <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
              {`${sapboxDataItem.sapboxName} | Started at: ${sapboxDataItem.startDate} ${' '}${sapboxDataItem.startTime}`}
            </AccordionSummary>
          </DialogTitle>
          <Grid sx={accordionTextbox}>
            <Typography style={{ padding: '1.4rem 2rem' }}>
              Initiated by: {userInfo.requestor}{' '}
              <span style={{ marginLeft: '2rem' }}> </span> Ended at: {userInfo.date_ended}{' '}
              {userInfo.time_ended}
              <span style={{ marginLeft: '1.4rem' }}> </span>
            </Typography>

            {sapboxCheckExists && matchingSapboxCheck.map((check, checkIndex) => (
              <Typography style={{ display: 'flex', marginLeft: '5.2rem' }} key={checkIndex}>
                Step Name: {check.step_name} <span style={{ marginLeft: '10rem' }}> </span>
                Status: {check.status} {check.sapbox_name}
             </Typography>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </Accordion>
      );
    })}
  </Box>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
```

historicalSapboxCheck

```
A6P: Array(1)
0: {id: 14, request_id: 10, requestor: 'Dummy Requestor10', step_name: 'step_template', sapbox_name: 'A6P', …}

L6P: Array(1)
0: {id: 13, request_id: 10, requestor: 'Dummy Requestor10', step_name: 'step_template', sapbox_name: 'L6P', …}
```

stepData

```
0: 
A6P: Array(2)
  0: {id: 2, request_id: 5, requestor: 'Dummy Requestor1', step_name: 'step_template', sapbox_name: 'A6P',   …}
  1: {id: 4, request_id: 5, requestor: 'Dummy Requestor1', step_name: 'step_template', sapbox_name: 'A6P', …}
L6P: (2) [{…}, {…}]

1: 
A6P: Array(1)
0: {id: 6, request_id: 6, requestor: 'Dummy Requestor1', step_name: 'step_template', sapbox_name: 'A6P', …}
L6P: [{…}]

2: {L6P: Array(1), A6P: Array(1)}
3: {L6P: Array(1), A6P: Array(1)}
4: {L6P: Array(1), A6P: Array(1)}
5: {L6P: Array(1), A6P: Array(1)}
```

I tried to do the .push(stepData) but the inside of the array is empty in typography